# Flow Resistance and Pressures in Split Pipes

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am doing some simple flow experiments and my instruments are giving me strange results - I think they are broken, I need a sanity check for my understanding of the flow in my system to confirm it.

Here is a schematic. An inlet has a gauge pressure of 19 inches of water gauge (19"wg).
The stream gets split up into two, pipes A and B. Both pipes lead to the same atmospheric pressure (Pe = 0).

I have denoted the net resistance in the two lines with $R_A$ and $R_B$.

Here is what I am wondering about: 
Do $P_A$ and $P_B$ necessarily have to be equal to 19"wg?
If I double the resistance RB, how will that affect the pressure PA?
If RB doubles, then the resistance in line B will be more, diverting more flow into line A. That means the velocity in line A has suddenly increased (since RA did not change). According to Bernoulli then, the pressure PA has to drop. Is this correct?

The principle of continuity applies where $Q_{in} = Q_A + Q_B$ and the energy per unit mass according Bernoulli, i.e. $\frac{P_{in}}{\rho} + \frac{V_{in}^2}{2} = \frac{P_A}{\rho} + \frac{V_{A}^2}{2} = \frac{P_B}{\rho} + \frac{V_{B}^2}{2}$

I am trying to think about this intuitively with a sort of hydraulic analogy - in terms of resistors, pressures and flows ($\frac{P}{R} = Q$).

[image: Split Pipe Flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming incompressible fluid here and rigid pipes (no compliance).

Before the actual physical split is there any appreciable resistance compared to RB and RA? If not then PA = PB = 19" wg.

If there is a significant resistance you need to include it in the model as Rin, and then

PA = PB = 19" *(RA || RB)/(Rin + RA || RB)

In any event PA = PB

Comment: Why is $P_A$ = $P_B$. Doesn't the pressure depend on downstream conditions. If one of the resistances increase, more flow is going to be diverted into the other pipe (velocity increases) and according to Bernoulli, the pressure is going to drop?

Comment: No. Not the pressure, the pressure drop or rather delta-pressure if you prefer. Your model is a 'lumped' component model, and that's how I treated it. With that assumption the resistances essentially collapse at single points in space. And anything outside of the resistance is considered zero resistance, so no pressure drops. The pressure is the same at each resistance inlet (upstream in the split). If one leg of the split has more resistance than the other there will be more pressure drop relative to the other resistance and the flow rate will be less.

Comment: It's the flow rate that changes not the upstream pressure.

Comment: Bernoulli's equation comes from the conservation of energy and energy is conserved. You can express your model in terms of mass  & energy conservation, but it's easier (for me at least) to use the analogy of electric circuits. That's how I derived the equations above - it's just a voltage divider.

Comment: So....if one resistance increases, the flow in that circuit, and therefore the total flow is going to drop?

Comment: In an ideal situation you consider the inlet pressure to be constant. So the mechanism causing causing flow keeps the pressure constant despite downstream loading - like a downstream regulator. So with that assumption if the total downstream resistance increases, the total flow will decrease. At the limits of infinite resistance the flow goes to zero, and the pressure regulator maintains at its setpoint of 13 psig. If on the other hand the inlet flow source does not have a low output impedance, the inlet pressure can change as downstream load changes...

Comment: And in that case the output flows can be affected by that as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. In this case there is a motor keeping the pressure constant upstream.